# How to build other folders in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a folder structure that is as follows:

```
|-CMakeLists.txt
|-main.cpp
|-network
 ---------- CMakeLists.txt
 ---------- network.h
 ---------- network.cpp
```

Where network is a folder containing the last 3 items.

I'm struggling to build this in CMake because the documentation is very strange to me. In my root CMakeLists.txt, it's as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.0)

project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/network")
add_subdirectory (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/network)

add_executable(server main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (network)

find_package(Boost 1.67 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)

# Check for libray, if found print message, include dirs and link libraries.
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message("Boost Found")
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(server ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(server Boost::thread)
elseif(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    error("Boost Not Found")
endif()
```

In the CMakeLists.txt in the network folder it's as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.0)

project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

install(FILES ${MY_HEADER_FILES} DESTINATION ./)

add_executable(network network.cpp)
```

I made that by myself playing around to see if I can get CMake to add the files in that folder into the root project. Obviously, this is all just failing because I'm struggling to understand CMake from the documentation. My apologies. I get an error due to the implementation in "network.cpp" not being recognized:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x409): undefined reference to `Socket::GetThis()'
```

I'm certain there's nothing wrong with the implementation because it's worked using another round about method but I want to build my project using the previous structure but I can't get my head around how to make the root CMakeLists and the network CMakeLists so that they work together.

How do I design the CMakeLists so that the network header and implementation are included in the root project. Also, the network library will be using Boost as well. Should I find the package in there too?

Comment: is network.cpp a library you wrote and use?

Comment: Yes. I wrote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
target_link_libraries (network)
```

You want to link "server" executable with "network" library. It's like this:

```
target_link_libraries(server PUBLIC network)
```

The `PUBLIC` can be omitted, but I like to specify it everywhere.

Also:

```
add_executable(network network.cpp)
```

should `network.spp` really be an executable? I guess there is no `main` in network.cpp`. You should:

```
add_library(network network.cpp)
```

And I guess the `network` include path is integral to the network library. So I would inside `network/CMakeLists.txt` do:

```
target_include_directories(network PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Also note the `target_compile_feature` is preferred over `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`.

Also, there is no `error()` function. There is `message(FATAL_ERROR)`.

All in all, I would write it like this:

```
# root/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.0)
project(Test)

# this tells cmake that all c++ files that are in this file
# and all in add_subdirectory projects
# will compile with C++11 (by default)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_subdirectory(network)

add_executable(server main.cpp)
# tell cmake to link server with network library
# ie. server executable uses network library
target_link_libraries(server PUBLIC network)

find_package(Boost 1.67 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
# Check for libray, if found print message, include dirs and link libraries.
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Boost Found")
    target_include_directories(server PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(server PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES} Boost::thread)
elseif(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost Not Found")
endif()
```

and:

```
# network/CMakeLists.txt
add_libraries(network network.cpp)
# tell cmake, that all targets that link with network library
# will have include path added 
target_include_directories(network PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

I link only server executable with boost. I have no idea if your `network` library needs to link with boost too, if so, move the boost info `netowrk/CMakeLists.txt` and `target_link_libraries(network PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change line

```
add_executable(server main.cpp)
```

to

```
add_executable(server main.cpp network.cpp)
```

P.S I personally prefer to use this construction:

```
SET(PROJECT_NAME "MyProject")
...
file(GLOB SRC_FILES *.cpp)
...
add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" "${SRC_FILES}")
```